# How to read a json file, find a key and bring the related data as object on Python?

Tags: python, json, xml

I'm kinda new to Python and hence learning by doing, so here I am asking for some heads up.

I need to store values in a JSON file, and later in the next execution check first if the user already requested access into the system to provide the proper returns.

So basically my json file will be:

```
{instance_id : 1111 {'username':'Dummy_User','email':'dummy@user.com','domain':'local','role':'admin','instance':'production','group':'administrators','state':'failed','description':'User Dummy_User is already a member of group administrators'}
},
{instance_id : 2222 {'username':'Dummy_User1','email':'dummy@user.com','domain':'local','role':'admin','instance':'production','group':'administrators','state':'success','description':'User Dummy_User1 added to the administrators group'}
}
```

I need to be able to query it by instance_id and get as return all of the fields, or a particular one.

Example:

```
result = checkJson(1111)
print (result.state + " - " + result.description)
>> failed - User Dummy_User is already a member of group administrators
```

What I'm currently doing: I'm writing the file using "with open" funcion but it is not separating the "objects" by comma in the file, hence it is not being recognizable as a valid json later

```
def write_json(self, data, filename): 
        with open(filename,'r+') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            json_data.update(data)
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(json_data, f)
```

Any thoughts on the best way to do that?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured. As per my example, I could get it done by:

Writing in the json:

```
userInput = {id : {"username":username,"adgroup":adgroup}}
filename = "path\to\file.json"

with open(filename,"r+") as f:
     json_data = json.load(f)
     json_data.update(data)
     f.seek(0)
     json.dump(json_data, f)
```

This will create an object of userInput and add to the json within the agregate structure.
Later, to read this json I used:

```
jsonFile = "path\to\file.json"
with open(jsonFile) as access:
     data = json.load(access)
     instance = data[id]['username']
     name = data[id]['adgroup']
```

where ID is the ID stored in the JSON to identify that object you saved before.